# Display the spark memory settings from the Driver Program

Tags: apache-spark

The `spark-submit` command line includes options for key memory settings:

- --executor-cores
- --executor-memory
- --num-executors
- --driver-memory

Are these settings accesible from within the `Driver` program? The intention would be to simply print them out to the logs.

Note that if the `spark.executor.cores` were set explicitly via jvm options then we could simply print out `System.getProperty("spark.executor.cores")`
. Similarly  for the other settings.  However the `spark-submit` command line options are *not* system properties and thus are not accessed in that parcticular manner.

Comment: have a lokk ot the REST API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api, especially the call `/applications/[app-id]/environment`

Comment: @RaphaelRoth That's interesting! I wonder when the rest server came into play.

Comment: Within the driver you can get the config with the following: spark.sparkContext.getConf.getAll